# GOPATH is looking into different path

Tags: go

I have set GOPATH and GOROOT in ~/.bashrc as:

`export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.10`

`export GOPATH=/home/user/go/pkg`

`export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin`

and whenever I try to build with go build main.go I am getting.

> main.go:4:2: cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/grpcdemo/pb" in any of:
>   /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/grpcdemo/pb (from $GOROOT)
>       /home/user/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/grpcdemo/pb (from $GOPATH)

The question is why is looking inside `home/user/go/src` as I have set the GOPATH to `/home/user/go/pkg`. So, I have expected package  inside`/home/user/go/pkg/src/google.golang.org/grpc/examples/grpcdemo/pb`.
Shouldn't it be looking inside `/home/user/go/pkg`?

Comment: Do **not** set GOROOT! And make sure you actually have $GOPATH/src and your bashrc is actually read.

Comment: @samrat_shakya Can you put the result of `$ go env`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably should have

```
export GOPATH=/home/user/go

export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

- don't use GOROOT at all (do `unset GOROOT` just to be safe )
- pkg is below GOPATH

Answer (score 1):

Run `$ go env` and check if the output contains the followings or not:

1. `GOPATH="/home/user/go"`
2. `GOROOT="/usr/local/go"`

If not, then use like bellow in your `~/.bashrc` file

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
# No need to set GOROOT since it is set /usr/local/go by default
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```

Now run `$ source ~/.bashrc` in bash. That's it.